# GPIO State Listener Example using Pi4J permanently triggers LOW-event

Tags: raspbian, java, pi4j

I have a Pi3 and I am trying out the example http://pi4j.com/example/listener.html which is a GPIO state listener.

My issue is the following:

When I press (close) the contact, I get **one** `HIGH` event.

When I release (open) the contact, I get `LOW/HIGH`-events permanently.

I tried to `debounce()` the events:

```
myButton.setDebounce(1000);
```

which really debounces the events. It means, with the contact opened I get *only* one (in fact two, it's one `LOW` immediately followed by a `HIGH`) per second.

I would like to get an event only on state changes.

How can that be achieved?

**Edit1**

It could be related to this issue https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/issues/121

Only difference is, I don't get the state changes randomly, but permanently in case the contact is open.

**Edit2**

Here someone has the same problem: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pi4j/hdVvEBCpRZc/HOdWFcSyHpIJ

**Edit3**

I opened an issue on pi4j's github about this problem: https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/issues/300

**Edit4**

At the end I was unable to reproduce the issue.